# How to work with Html() JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was practicing JQuery.

```
html()
```

and my `html()` function was working fine

```
<span>Hello</span>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

(function(){

    $('div').html('<span>Hello <b>Again</b></span>');

})();
```

But it stops working when I put bootstrap classes. What is the reason?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <span>Hello</span>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to give selector reference for div, try `$('div.col-lg-12').html('<span>Hello <b>Again</b></span>');`

Comment: maybe because the content of `<div class="container">` is replaced with `<span>Hello <b>Again</b></span>`

Comment: [It seems to be working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/f1vptnrm/) however the results might not be what you expected. The very first `div` that is matched gets all of it's contents swapped for that `span` element you are inserting. What is your expected output?

Comment: The question is not well expressed. What does "stops working" mean? Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: *"but it stops working"* isn't proper explanation of a problem

Comment: i just wanted to know if there is a possible way to give parent containers the same functionality . See my fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/5nwbu4ro/

Comment: when i'm not using bootstrap its coming like this :https://jsfiddle.net/5nwbu4ro/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('div')` will give you a list of all `div` including

`div.container`
`div.row`
`div.col-lg-12`
`div` 
`div`
`div`

`.html('<span>Hello <b>Again</b></span>')` will iterate through them and change their `HTML` content to what you provided. In effect once `div.container`'s content gets replaced with `span` no other `div` will remain in your `DOM`. So you have to somehow differentiate the `div` that need to be changed from the `div` that need not be.

`div.col-lg-12 > div` can be a possible selection. It refers to all `div` that are immediate child of the `div` with `class` `col-lg-12`

> Do not think that `$('div')` will select only `div` without class
>   names. it will actually select all nodes in `DOM` with tag name `div` irrespective of their class names or `id`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to find specific div with class or id of the div like

```
$('div.col-lg-12').html('<span>Hello <b>Again</b></span>');
```

It will add html inside   as you expected.

Comment: you should edit your answer to fix the code formatting

Answer (score -5):

you need to specify cssclass for div like `$('div.col-lg-12').html(...)`

Comment: will not have the same behavior, would do `$('div.col-lg-12 div')`